# Have a question about backtracking for parsing string

Tags: depth-first-search, backtracking

Given a string of numbers, you need to parse this string and then use + or - between numbers. If the result of calculation is equal to 100, add this combo to result.

Example input:
"991"
Example output:
["9+91", "99+1"]

Please let me know if you have thought on this. Python is preferred. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have n digits, then a brute-force solution would be to try and put one of three possible cases between each two digits, the possibilities are ('+','-',''(nothing)), the time complexity of this solution is 3^(d-1), where d is the number of digits in the input string.